# Why the Chrome cannot display the web page correctly when the windows is minimized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am trying to build custom video control.

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            video {
                transform: scale(-1, 1);
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="p-1">
        <div class="border-top border-primary container-fluid">
            <div class="h-25 row">
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary col-6 d-flex flex-column p-1" style="box-sizing:border-box">
                    <div class="bg-primary h-75 text-white">
                        sdfsfd
                    </div>
                    <div class="bg-secondary h-25 text-danger">
                        9080
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-right border-primary col-6 d-flex flex-column p-1">
                    <video id="remoteView" autoplay muted>
                        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="align-items-center border-left border-bottom border-right border-primary col-12 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center p-0">
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle d-flex justify-content-center p-1">
                        <button class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-success">A</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle d-flex justify-content-center p-1">
                        <button class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-success">B</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group-toggle d-flex justify-content-center p-1">
                        <button class="btn-sm btn btn-lg btn-success">C</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The upper left cell cannot be displayed correctly when the Chrome browser window is minimized.

However, in the Firefox browser, the problem does not exist.

How can I fix it?

Comment: height: 100vh;   is the   Css to make video  height as per  device height

Comment: Sorry, it is because my understanding the problem incorrectly, so I update the problem.

Comment: @TheKNVB Can you clarify what you mean when you say "minimized"?  Normally, this would make the window invisible, so you shouldn't be able to see anything.  While some window managers (like Windows Explorer) will allow you to see a thumbnail, this is often cached.  You can also see in script that Chrome will stop painting the screen completely, or will only do it once every second.  In extreme cases, the whole page context can be paused.

Comment: Sorry, I mean shrink the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

```
video { height: 100vh; min-height: 100%; }
```

You can get more details about video fullscreen, following this [`How to - Fullscreen Video`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp)

Comment: Sorry, it is because my understanding the problem incorrectly, so I update the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
In most cases it will fix the problem.